# Data dictionary report tool

Tags: oracle, powerdesigner

I am asked to extract the oracle database dictionary from a tool. They used to do that with power designer 12.5. 
They generate a report and it represents in a html format. This report includes all tables and columns information’s, and programmers easily can ready it. The bad thing about it, it needs about a week to make such report (reverse engineering, customizing...). They are trying to find a fast tool so they can generate a daily data dictionary tool. 
For now i have found *Oracle Data Modeler*, but I will download it to see if its a fast tool.
my question: do you know a fast tool to quickly generate a data dictionary report ?

Comment: What information do they need in the report? I'm asking with regard of your comment that the reverse engineering was taking a day: you can select the information you want to be reversed, in order to have a faster R.E. procedure...

Comment: @pascal only tables and columns , about 400 tables. i have never extract a data dictionary before using power designer. But now i am searching for a quick tool to extract it and organized in nice way. i will try to post an image showing how powerdesigner organized it in a really beautiful easy way , as i meantioned its about 400 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle's SQL Developer tool will produce an html formatted data dictionary very quickly and easily, as I recall. The data modeller functionality is probably more complex than you need.

Comment: i will download it and check it. thank you.

Comment: i have installed oracle SQL Developr and i saw how it generate report. it is really simple report and not well orginzed as powerdesigner report. i will check data modeller and see its good

Comment: I believe that you have to reverse engineer the schema into Data Modeller and proceed from there. I never really had much luck with that, but have not tried it for over a year -- I think there are restrictions on the free version.

Comment: yes i have to reverse enginneer too for powerdesigner, it took me about a day to finish reverse enginneering, anyway if there are restrictions ill stick too powerdesigner. anyway i will try it first thanks you for your advices david

Comment: the software was really good. There are few bad things but its somhow good. powerdesigner offer many things extra but oracle data modeler is for free ( i have checked the pricing and defenilty for free )

Comment: i can't vote up hope some one can do that for me :) thanks you

Answer (score 0):

the poor mans solution :
generate html report from sqlplus

```
break on owner , table_name skip 1
set html markup on 
spool dailyDataDictionaryReport.html

select  owner,table_name,column_name,data_type,data_length,data_precision
from    all_tab_columns
where   owner not in ('SYS','SYSOPER','XDB');

spool off
set html markup off
```

I think TOAD might have a good wziard for that.

Comment: i canno't access [TOAD](http://toadfororacle.com/index.jspa?product=toadfororacle) Community, it seems for maintenance reason, as for the querry , i dunno if it will represent the results as i want but i will give it a try and i will reply to you. thanks Haki