# Create Data dictionary of database B

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration, data-dictionary

I have 2 database server main database A and other database B.

Database B is same as A but the name of tables and some of the field name are different, but data inside is almost the same.

Database B as some minor modification to number of fields/column in the tables but that doesn't matter.

I need to make a data dictionary for Database B. What software can I use to make Data dictionary.

Comment: what do you meen by "making a data dictionary" ? if you want to access  dictionary tables from db A in db B create a db link and query `all_tables@db_b`. if you want to compare the structure TOAD provides a good tool for that. be more specific.

Comment: I want map of all the tables in whole database so I can write data dictionary, in pdf or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517447/data-dictionary-report-tool)

Answer (score 0):

There'is a tool called DATABASE ENGINE 4...

Check this for further informations

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRMUReSENjU